# Loop with matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Suppose,I have a matrix of 10 X 100 as follow (actually matrix quite big):

```
x = matrix(norm(n=10), 10, 100)
```

Now I want to make 1000 by 1 matrix by combining column 1 though 100. [for example like `rbind`.

my code is as follow:

```
y=matrix(0,nrow=1000,ncol=1) 

for(row in 1:10){
y[1+(row-1)*100:(row)*100, 1]=x[row,1:100] 
}
```

My expected output is something like this

```r
y=matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=1000, ncol=1)
```

Somehow my code does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Maybe just `matrix(x)` ?

Comment: @Dave2e Do you mean here: ```y=matrix(0,nrow=1000,ncol=1) ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the dimensions of the matrix:

```
x <- matrix(1:100, 5, 20)
y <- matrix(x, 100, 1)
```